# Как вызвать 2 функции echo php?

Tags: php

уважаемые гуру stackoferflow.

В базе данных есть столбец "echofilms" в которой строка содержит текст вызова функции **boeviki();**

Функция **boeviki()**

```
function boeviki(){
global $db;
$singles = $db->query("SELECT id FROM singles WHERE genre LIKE '%Боевик%'"); 
return $singles->rowCount();}
```

**Как мне её вызвать на сайт через базу данных MySQL?** Так-же используя PHP

Вызывал так, но не помогло.

```
<?php echo $single["echofilms"]; ?>
<?= <?php echo $single["echofilms"]; ?> ?>
```

Comment: eval использовать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а как именно?

Comment: `<?php eval($single["echofilms"]);  echo boeviki(); ?>`

Comment: если eval не устроит, попробуйте текстовую линковку. `<? function x(){rerurn 'abc';} $w='x'; echo $w();// echo abc?>` но в любом случае не рекомендую пользоваться подобными вызовами, тем более когда имя вызываемой функции или хуже того, её код получаешь из БД(не безопасно это).

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а если в базе данных например drama(); , как мне вывести и boeviki() и drama ()?

Comment: ...по аналогии соответственно

Comment: Можете код написать пожалуйста? чуточку не понял...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне надо вывести все функции drama()/boevik() в один <li></li>, не понимаю как..